# I have written the following code for a neural network, but I am getting a ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I have written the following code for a neural network to perform regression on a dataset, but I am getting a ValueError

```
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from numpy import loadtxt
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense

data1_train = pd.read_csv('../input/car-security/DoS_dataset.csv',
names=["Timestamp", "CAN ID", "DLC", "DATA[0]", "DATA[1]", "DATA[2]", "DATA[3]", 
"DATA[4]", "DATA[5]", "DATA[6]", "DATA[7]", "Flag"])

data1_train.head()

#Splitting dataset to know if the data is injected or normal
data1_features = data1_train.copy()
data1_labels = data1_features.pop('Flag')

data1_features = np.array(data1_features)
data1_features

array([[1478198376.389427, '0316', 8, ..., '21', '00', '6f'],
[1478198376.389636, '018f', 8, ..., '3c', '00', '00'],
[1478198376.389864, '0260', 8, ..., '8e', '6d', '3a'],
...,
[1478201209.058471, '02a0', 8, ..., '02', 'bd', '00'],
[1478201209.058703, '0329', 8, ..., '20', '00', '14'],
[1478201209.058944, '0545', 8, ..., '00', '00', '00']],
dtype=object)

#regression model to predict data
data1_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
layers.Dense(11),
layers.Dense(2)
])

 data1_model.compile(loss = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(),
              optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam())

 data1_model.fit(data1_features, data1_labels, epochs=10)
```

I get:

```
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type float).
```

Comment: Where exactly? Please post a [mre].

Comment: `data1_features` is either jagged or has mixed data types. It looks like it has mixed data types. The dtype should be a float, not object. Even some of the shown values are strings. Try `data1_features = np.asarray(data1_features).astype(np.float32)` maybe?

Comment: As mentioned by @Djinn, you have a mix of data types which is inherently difficult to convert to tensor, use tf datasets to do this and return a dictionary as an output

Comment: @Djinn Thank you for your response when I tried giving me this error msg ValueError: could not convert string to float: '018f'

Comment: @Edwin Cheong Thank you for your response. Can you please write a code as an example? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As requested by uka here's an example using tf datasets

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def map_data(input_data):
    # input_data is a dictionary
    # do something with input_data, make sure you return as dictionary
    input_data['input']
    return input_data

# Here you can add many key, val as you want, mapping is up for you to decide
sample_data = {'inputs': np.random.randn(100, 1, 100)}
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(sample_data)
dataset = dataset.map(map_data, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

# Grab an example from dataset
sample = next(iter(dataset))

# Use for model prediction
model.predict(dataset)
```